# Broken layout after portrait/landscape change

Tags: bug, ios-app

Got this layout bug while rotating the iPad from portrait to landscape while it was loading content. It happened right after I tapped the topic in the sidebar.

[image: broken layout]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)